# Save 2 Forms At the Same Time MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im planning to save 2 forms but the 1st form is where i get the Foreign key for the Second form

This is my Attempt to save this Using Javascript

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#workForm').submit();
        $('#conttForm').submit();
    });
```

But it errors on Contact Form Submit because the ID of Worker Form is still null while saving the contact form that is its Foreign Key

i also Tried this method

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        if (Id != 0) {
            $('#workForm').submit();
            $('#contForm').submit();
        } else {
           $('#workForm').submit(); }
    });
```

But it only go at Else because the ID is 0

I hope someone can help me here

Thanks :D

Comment: What are you doing with the forms when submitted?  I assume you are sending them via ajax. So why not create a callback on the ajax post of the first form and than submit the second in that callback.

Comment: I'm not master of MVC. But, if your only purpose of doing this is to save all the related data, you can use ORM like NHibernate or EF and it'll manage those relationships.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `submit` function actually causes the browser to send a request, i.e. you're submitting the form. To accomplish this you'll need to uses ajax. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $('#workForm').attr('action'),
    data: $('#workForm').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        //grab whatever id you need here
        var id_thing = $(data).find('#id_here').val();
        //do something with id
        $('#conttForm input[name="your-hidden-id-field"]').val(id_thing);
        $('#conttForm').submit();
    }
})
```

Comment: is there another way to solve this using jquery and not using ajax? Thanks!

Comment: We only use Javascript and we avoid to use ajax

Comment: Maybe. If you can post some more details, like what the forms look like, and what exactly `Id` is and where it comes from.

Comment: i add image of my form looks like @matthewG

Comment: hahaha, I meant the html for the forms. Sorry, i wasn't very clear.

Comment: Right, basically the only way to do this on one page without passing the value of the worker id to the view is via ajax. I would suggest redesigning this app to have the worker address form be submitted to a new view that has the worker contact form. Then the worker id should already be available in your controller method.